HTTP 404.0 Not Found in IIS with ASP.NET Core 6
As the title says, I'm having a problem when I try to route my ASP.NET Core 6 MVC web application (the route it's done with app.MapControllers() in the Program.cs), in IIS as this screenshot shows:

I have Windows 10 pro, so when I start the solution from visual studio community, it automatically creates the deployment in iis (as per the configuration in launchSettings.json) as seen below:

I'm able to see the landing page of my web app (_ViewStart.cshtml):

But when I try to change page by routing, for example, trying to press
the button "Borsa" (or any other button by routing)

I get an http 404 error (as in the screenshot above), but I can't understand why because, when I try to use the inbuild kestrel or IISExpress, I'm able to route without any problems, but with IIS, I'm having some Route problems and I can't understand why.
Here I leave the image that it works with IISExpress:

Below I leave the image of the settings with which I installed IIS (I have installed everything with desperation :') ):

[
I'm adding the application pool configuration that the web app it's using and the settings of the app pool:




Thank you if you can help me (and sorry for my bad English)
If you need more information please let me know! Thanks!
I expect that there's no issue with routing, I have tried everything I could

Simply because your habit of writing links in your code. If you have existing links referencing "/borsa" directly, update them to use the @Url.Action or Html.ActionLink approach to resolve the 404 error. Your app is hosted under a site, so the actual links should contain the path of that IIS application. It worked with IIS Express because you host it as a site there.

YES!, thank you very much!!!, I was writing the link as Borsa but using your suggestion '<a href="@Url.Action("Index", "HttpClientBorsa")">Borsa'  I have solved this issue, thank you very much!

Did you installed the ASP.NET Core 6.0 Hosting Bundle on the Server where IIS is hosted?
You can install the hosting bundle from https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/6.0
Let me know if you still face the issue.

I have installed, do an iisreset, restarted the computer but, nothing, still the problem persist :(

@JosephfranciscoCubasBallon Can you please post the application pool configuration in which the application is running?

Hi, I have added (above) the app pool configuration in which the application is running

Totally irrelevant.
